# Realm access from incorrect thread Exception while a copy was sent using copyFromRealm

Tags: java, android, multithreading, realm, rx-java

When streaming copy of realm objects instead of realm reference and observing it on Schedulers.IO thread, there is a crash with the famous exception message "Realm access from incorrect thread. Realm objects can only be accessed in the thread they were created."

Shouldn't the copy be thread free? Can I produce it from one thread and process it on a different thread?

This is how I am creating observable.

```
 public Observable<Brand> getAllBrands() {
    return realm.where(Brand.class)
            .findAll()
            .asObservable()
            .flatMap(Observable::from)
            .map(brand -> realm.copyFromRealm(brand));
}
```

Following is how I observe getAllBrands().

```
 Observable<Brand> brandObservable = dataManager.getAllBrands();

    brandObservable.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .subscribe(new Observer<Brand>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {
                    Log.d("reactive", "completed");
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    Log.d("reactive", e.getMessage());
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(Brand brand) {
                    dataSource.add(brand.getName());
                    myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });
```

Comment: The `realm` you're using is not on the `io()` scheduler.

Answer (score 7):

You are subscribing on `schedulers.io` while using the Realm instance from the UI thread:

```
realm.where(Brand.class)
        .findAll()
        .asObservable()
        .flatMap(Observable::from)
        .map(brand -> realm.copyFromRealm(brand)) // realm instance on the wrong thread
        .subscribeOn(schedulers.io());
```

What are you after is an easy way to move a query across threads, which is still work-in-progress here: https://github.com/realm/realm-java/pull/1978. Until then you can work around it by doing it yourself like this:

```
public Observable<Brand> getAllBrands(final Realm realm) {
    return Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<List<Brand>>() {
        @Override
        public void call(final Subscriber<? super List<Brand>> subscriber) {
            Realm obsRealm = Realm.getInstance(realm.getConfiguration());
            final RealmResults<Brand> results = obsRealm.where(Brand.class).findAll();
            final RealmChangeListener listener = new RealmChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onChange() {
                    subscriber.onNext(realm.copyFromRealm(results));
                }
            };
            results.addChangeListener(listener);
            subscriber.add(Subscriptions.create(new Action0() {
                @Override
                public void call() {
                    realm.removeChangeListener(listener);
                    realm.close();
                }
            }));

        }
    })
    .flatMap(Observable::from);
}
```

Note that Realm Changelisteners only work on Looper threads which means you probably need to change your worker thread to a H

```
HandlerThread bgThread = new HandlerThread("workerThread");
Handler handler = new Handler(bgThread.getLooper());

getAllBrands(realm).subscribeOn(HandlerScheduler.from(handler));
```

Comment: I am not trying to move a query across threads. Instead, I am trying to stream the copy of detached Realm objects. Isn't it possible to use detached data across multiple threads irrespective of realm instant that created it ?

Comment: It is, but in `map(brand -> realm.copyFromRealm(brand));` brand is objects created on the UI thread and accessed on the `schedulers.io()` thread. My solution is a work-around for that (by executing the query on the `schedulers.io()` thread)

Comment: Now I am getting "You can't register a listener from a non-Looper thread".

Comment: RealmChangeListeners only work on Looper thread, my bad. This means that you cannot use `Schedulers.io()` if you want continous updates. Instead you can use the RxAndroids HandlerSchedulers. I have updated the answer

Comment: @ChristianMelchior Based on this approach, should I use one started instance of HandlerThread for all my Realm read calls (and if so, should I never call HandlerThread.quit)? 
Or should I create a new HandlerThread for each call and then quit that thread during the unsubscription?
And what if there are, for example, multiple different (simultaneous) calls and running HandlerThread's instances?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hi @Augusent did you ever get an answer to your question? I am also wondering about the same thing

Comment: Why is there on `onComplete` call? It makes my observable load cotinuously

Answer (score 0):

**QUESTION**

> Can I produce it from one thread and process it on a different thread?

Answer is NO. You can read the description of realm in [here](http://realm.io)

> Although Realm files can be accessed by multiple threads concurrently, you cannot hand over Realms, Realm objects, queries, and results between threads. The thread example shows how to use Realm in a multithreading environment.

Comment: But the question is about detached objects using `copyFromRealm()` which are supposedly not associated with a Realm instance.